# Playframework: Assets are not updated in production mode when changed

Tags: html, web-applications, playframework, playframework-2.2

I created a mobile html5 web with the playframework 2.x. Users are able to upload images via the app, which then are stored on the server the app is running on.

Images are stored in `public/images`and acessed like this: `@routes.Assets.at(images/images1.jpg)`

My problem is that whenever a user is uploading an image to my server and then is trying to view the uploaded image afterwards, the image can`t be displayed.

I found out that whenever I restart the play process on the server, then the newly uploaded image will be displayed correctly. I normally start my production server like this:

```
activator dist
```

and afterwards unzip the created zip directory and run the generated script.

I figured that the problem is that when the app is packed it will only pack the assets available at the time in the assets.jar and therefore not be able to show new images which are added after the server is started.

---

**So my question is, what do I need to change so that images, which are changed or added while the server is running are displayed correctly, without having to repack and restart the app.**

---

My routes file

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET        /                                 controllers.Application.index

# Used in Javascript to push new User into Database via Ajax
PUT        /users/:i                         controllers.Userdata.addUser(i: Int)

... similiar PUT Requests ...

PUT        /deactUser/:i                     controllers.Userdata.deactUser(i: Int)

GET        /reloadUsers                      controllers.Userdata.reloadUsers(minA: Int, maxA: Int, gend: String, orient: String, verf: String)

GET         /ads                             controllers.Application.getAds()

# Javascript Router
GET        /assets/javascripts/routes        controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET        /assets/*file                     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating dist package the `public` folder is accessed from created `*.jar` file, therefore you need to re-dist your app to make uploaded files available in it.

Instead you should create some directory in filesystem and define its path (preferably via configuration file), so you will upload files and serve them into/from *independent* location. Of course you'll need to write custom action to serve them as well, but that's just several lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you explain a bit more what you mean with custom action?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what to implement in practise:

In your routes file, add something like this:

```
GET         /customImage/:name        controllers.Application.imageAt(name:String)
```

Then implement imageAt like this:

```
public Result imageAt(String imageName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File imageFile = new File("/path/to/image"+imageName);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {
        String resourceType = "image+"+imageName.substring(imageName.length()-3);
        return ok(new FileInputStream(imageFile)).as(resourceType);
    } else {
        return notFound(imageFile.getAbsoluteFile());
    }
}
```

And that's it. Anything you put to "/path/to/image" will be accessible via url /customerImage/
They can also be accessible via revert routes like @routes.Application.imageAt(imageName)